# call to an overloaded function while calling template

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguous

I am calling a template for finding a min out of two values 
The code is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
T min(T a,T b)
{
    return (a<b)?a:b;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int d,y;
std::cout<<"enter two integer values";
std::cin>>d>>y;
cout<<"you entered"<<d<<y;
std::cout<<"the minimum of the two is "<<min(d,y);
float p,q;
std::cout<<"enter float values";
std::cin>>p>>q;
cout<<"you entered"<<p<<q;
std::cout<<"the minimum of the float values is "<<min(p,q);
char w,a;
std::cout<<"enter the two characters";
std::cin>>w>>a;
cout<<"you entered"<<w<<a;
std::cout<<"the minimum of the two characters is "<<min(w,a);
return 0;
```

}

It says call to an ovrloaded function is ambiguous

Comment: you know there is std::min?

Comment: More specifically, `template< class T > const T& std::min( const T& a, const T& b )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
using namespace std;
```

because there is another min() function in std.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because there is a standard function called [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) defined in the namespace `std`, which your program allowed the compiler to use without an explicit reference.

Remove

```
using namespace std;
```

and add `std::` qualifier to `cout` where it's missing to fix this problem.

[Demo of your program compiling on ideone](http://ideone.com/gp85KY).

Answer (score 0):

Use `::min(d,y)` to indicate that you refer to the function in the global namespace.